# Temporary Table and Left Joins not showing results as expected

Tags: php, mysql, left-join, temp-tables

I'm really hoping someone can help me with this.  I have a number of product attribute types that users can select from to refine the products that are returned to them on screen. What I'm trying to do is, for each product attribute type, I want to list all attributes that relate to either the selected category or search term, then once they've made their selections, I still want to display each of the attributes that relate to the category or search term, but only display a clickable link if the product count for that particular attribute is greater than 1 and for those that have a product count of zero, I want to list them, but make them unclickable. An example of what I'm trying to achieve can be found on the ASOS website, in the left hand menu 
http://www.asos.com/Women/Dresses/Cat/pgecategory.aspx?cid=8799#state=Rf961%3D3340%2C3341%40Rf-200%3D20&parentID=Rf-300&pge=0&pgeSize=20&sort=-1

Initially I tried using just joins to achieve this, but I wasn't able to do it, successfully.  So I decided to create a temporary table for each attribute type which held a list of all the attributes that related to the main query and then created a refined query, with a left join.  Here's my code:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table 
    SELECT su_types.id, type AS item FROM su_types 
    INNER JOIN su_typerefs ON su_types.id=su_typerefs.id 
    INNER JOIN su_pref ON su_typerefs.mykey = su_pref.mykey 
WHERE wp_category_id =40 GROUP BY su_typerefs.id

$sudb->query($query);

if ($sudb->affected_rows > 0) {     

SELECT temp_table.id,item,COUNT(su_typerefs.mykey) AS product_count FROM temp_table 
    LEFT JOIN su_typerefs ON temp_table.id=su_typerefs.id 
    LEFT JOIN su_pref ON su_typerefs.mykey = su_pref.mykey 
    LEFT JOIN su_stylerefs ON su_pref.mykey = su_stylerefs.mykey 
    LEFT JOIN su_productrefs ON su_pref.mykey = su_productrefs.mykey
WHERE wp_category_id =40 AND su_stylerefs.id in (91) AND su_productrefs.id in (54) AND su_typerefs.id in (159) GROUP BY su_typerefs.id

if ($itemresults = $sudb->query($query)) {

    while($itemresult = $itemresults->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $id=$itemresult['id'];
    $item=$itemresult['item'];
    $product_count=$itemresult['product_count'];


        build_link($list_type, $item, $product_count, $id);
    }
}
```

In the above example the first query selects all the product types that relate to a particular category, say dresses. And the second query is based on the refinements the user has made on the category, in this example this is product, product type and style. A user can also refine their search by colour, fit, fabric and design.

There are a couple of issues with this:

1) The number of results returned in the second query do not match the results of the first.  Using the above as an example, I wish to list all products that relate to the chosen category, then using the second query return the product count for each of these products as I described above.  So if the temporary table returns, trousers, jeans and skirts.  I expected these three items to be displayed on screen based on the conditions applied in the second query, however my results may only show trousers and jeans, if there is not a match for skirts in the second query.  I thought that using a left join would mean that all the results of the temporary table would be displayed.

2)Also I wonder if I'm doing this the most efficient way.  I have a total of 8 attribute groups, and therefore need to do the above 8 times.  If the user choses to refine the results using all 8 attribute groups then in addition to the temp table join, there will be a total of 9 joins for each type.  It's taking a while to execute, is there a better way to do this?  There are approximately 1/2 million products in the table, and this will probably be 5 times this, once my site goes live.

I really hope all that I have written makes sense and I'd really appreciate the stackoverflow community's help with this, if anyone can help. I apologise for the essay ;).  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question; yes, a LEFT JOIN will indeed keep all data from the initial table. That, however, isn't the problem.

The reason why you lose empty categories, is most likely (I say this because I don't fully know your db structure) because of the where condition filtering out all results based on the data in the joined tables.
If for a category all items get filtered out (possibly including the NULL joined values), you will not get this category back from that query anymore. Also the GROUP BY is done on a joined column, that might also effectively wipe out your other categories.

As for the second question, you already state it's taking long; so it's probably not the way to go if you want things to work fast ;) (okay, obvious answer, low hanging fruit, etc). What you might want to do, is get a collection of keys from the filterable categories first, and use that data to select items.

This prevents that you have to join up your entire products table in a temp table (at least, that's what I think you're doing), which of course will take long with the given number of entries. Selecting a list of matching IDs from the given attributes also gives you the advance of using your indexes (more), which a temp-table probably won't have. If this is possible and feasible mainly depends on your schema's structure; but I hope it might lead you to the direction you want to go :)

Comment: Hi Yhn, thanks for your reply, the temp table isn't retrieving all attributes from the table, but only the ones that relate to the chosen category.  I had previously constructed the second query as a loop through each of the keys that I wanted a count for.  That worked perfectly, but it took the same amount of time, if not more.  It's taking approximately 30 seconds to load the full page at the moment, and that's not acceptable is it?

Comment: 30 seconds for just some count statistics do sound like it should be able to work better... You could try to check the timings of both queries (just to confirm which of both is actually causing issues). After that you could try to use the output of EXPLAIN [query] to see if indices are correctly used for the joins and where. Maybe it can work faster without the temp table (since that might not have indices; while the actual tables have).

Comment: I tried to do an explain on the temp table query but I wasn't able to.  But an explain on the sedond query looked fine.  If I don't use the temp table, then I'd have to create the second query which loops through the first, rather than joining the second query to the temp table and returning all results in one hit

Comment: My experience with joining big tables (even with constraining where's), is that is takes way too long with MySQL.. you might have the same problem. The way I work with said large table (in my case, 5.5mil records) is to gather selection criteria first (in the form of ids present in that large table) and then use that to select useful rows from the large table by using the indices. This might speed things up for you too. As for the category not showing up; changing your GROUP BY to the temp table 'id' field might fix it (as that field is always present with the joins).